# Find a surface and a 2-form on it that is not of the form $d\omega$.

Tags: manifolds, smooth-manifolds, surfaces, differential-forms

I want to find a surface and a smooth 2-form on it that is *not* of the form $d\omega$.

I know a theorem that says: every closed 1-form on $S^2$ is exact. So my hunch is that $S^2$ is a candidate for a surface. It isn't clear to me how to really construct such a 2-form though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On any orientable compact manifold, the volume form $\omega$ is not exact. If it were, then it would integrate to zero by Stokes' theorem, which contradicts the fact that it is positive everywhere.

So you can take $M = S^2$ and $\omega = \sin \theta \, \mathrm{d}\theta \wedge \mathrm{d} \phi $.

Comment: Of course, your $\omega$ *is* exact — take $d(-\cos\theta\,d\phi)$. What's the resolution of this paradox?

Comment: @TedShifrin Yes, my specification of $\omega$ was somewhat sloppy. In fact $\omega$ as above is not defined at the poles $\theta = 0, \pi$, on account that $\mathrm{d} \phi$ is not defined there. We should more properly introduce another coordinate system that is well defined at the poles, and give $\omega$ on that patch also.

Comment: Ah, of course! Now I get it too. Thanks!